# Как лучше передавать команды серверу java

Tags: java, сокет, сервер

Допустим есть сервер, имеющий 2 основных метода: вернуть значение какой-то переменной и обновить её значение. И есть клиент, который отправляет запрос и получает либо значение, либо уведомление о том, что данные получены. Как такое организовать? Что передавать по сети? Обычный текст? Сериализованные объекты с инструкциями серверу?

PS: Лучшим ответом будет ссылка на какую-нибудь статью или мануал...

Comment: Для описанной задачи подойдет все что угодно. Если появляются требования к производительности, безопасности и т.п., то нужно смотреть отдельно.

Comment: @avp, можете оформить этот комментарий как ответ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@Dazar](/users/9259/dazar)](/users/9259/dazar), чем проще протокол, тем лучше. В Вашем случае (на самом деле Вы не полностью специфицировали свою задачу), видимо самым простым будет обмен строками с текстом.

Связываете tcp сокет с потоком ввода-вывода и гоняете строки. В каждой команда и соответствующие данные. Полностью аналогично вводу-выводу с терминала.

--

IMHO это настолько очевидно, что вряд ли кто-то станет писать специальные мануалы (и статьи).

Answer (score 1):

Единственное, добавлю к avp на всякий случай использовать спецсимволы для разделения строк (сообщений) между собой.